# Detecting agent app launch and termination without polling on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, agent, nsworkspace

I need to be able to detect agent app launch and termination without polling on Mac OS X

Apple’s technical note TN2050 suggests using NSWorkspace or Kqueues.

It appears that NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotifications wouldn’t work with agent app. I don’t fully understand why, but it is sensitive to presence of LSUIElement=1 attribute.

KQueue API can only detect process termination using NOTE_EXIT and will successfully detect exit of the app agent. However there no way to detect app launch event using this API.

I also experimented with Kernel Authorization subsystem and discovered that it is possible to detect agent launch using either KAUTH_SCOPE_VNODE with KAUTH_VNODE_EXECUTE or KAUTH_SCOPE_FILEOP with KAUTH_FILEOP_EXEC. However I failed to find a way to detect process termination using KAuth.

Is there a better way of detecting agent app launch and termination, other than using a combination of KAuth to detect launch and KQueue to detect termination?

Thanks